# What to call measures obtained between pre-test and post-test?

Tags: experimental-psychology, test

We term pre-test as the data collection/measures before conducting an experiment and post-test is data collection/measures after the experiment. How do we term the process of data collection/measures during the experiment (such as physiological measures)? I am looking for a specific "term" to describe the "during-test" event.

Comment: "Test", perhaps?

Comment: About the only things I could find called them intermediary or ongoing assessment testing.

Answer (score 3):

People use a wide range of language to describe measurement points in repeated measures design.

For example if you measured some dependent variable on multiple occasions you might have something like:

1. baseline (B)
2. treatment week 1 (T1)
3. treatment week 2 (T2)
4. post treatment (F0)
5. six month follow up (F6)
6. one year follow (F12)

Obviously such a design has aspects that are consistent with a pre-post test design, but it has more time points than just that. So my suggestion is to just have clear descriptive labels for the measurement points.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the prefix you're looking for is *per*.  In latin, *pre* means "in front of", *per* means "through" and *post* means behind.

Comment: A "per-test" eh? Ever seen that used? Google seems to think I am searching for "per test", as in, "One cookie per test only please."

Comment: I haven't heard "per-test" in the wild, but the linguistically speaking, the progression is "pre-per-post", so you *could* use it and it would make sense.  Frankly, though, I'd just say "pre-test", "test" and "post-test".